# C#/LINQ: Trying to optimize performance

Tags: c#, linq

This is my setup

```
class EditorTabViewModel : TabViewModel {
    ...
    public bool CanSave { get; set; };
}

ObservableCollection<TabViewModel> _tabs
```

I want to check if there are any tabs in `_tabs` that are `EditorTabViewModel` that has property `CanSave` set to true

i did something like ...

```
var tabs = from t in _tabs
            where t is EditorTabViewModel
            && ((EditorTabViewModel)t).CanSave == true
            select t;
if (tabs.Count() > 0)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

I wonder if there is a better way to do this? maybe i won't need to retrieve all tabs, or maybe I just need to query the count or something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about:

```
return _tabs.OfType<EditorTabViewModel>().Any(t => t.CanSave);
```

Here:

- `OfType<>` is a non-buffering filter that restricts us to `EditorTabViewModel`
- `Any` is short-circuiting, so returns true as soon as a match is found

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can improve. Something like this would probably work:

```
return _tabs.Any(x => x is EditorTabViewModel && ((EditorTabViewModel)x).CanSave);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the linq extensions you could write something like

`_tabs.Any( p => p is EditorTabViewModel && ((EditorTabViewModel)t).CanSave)`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
return _tabs.FirstOrDefault(y => y is EditorTabViewModel && ((EditorViewModel)t).CanSave) != null;
```

Comment: `SingleOrDefault` must still consume the entire sequence, to ensure that there aren't *two* matches. Indeed, this will have a different outcome (an exception) to the original code (which would return true) when there are multiple tabs that can be saved.